# Blackberry app that periodically sends GPS to webserver?

Tags: blackberry, web, background, gps

I want to create a background app on a Blackberry that starts when the phone boots and sends gps locations to a webserver periodically. Is this possible *without* the BES server? I am most likely targeting OS 4.5. Any gotchas I should know about?

thanks
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only background process.

[How to - Set up a background application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800660/How_To_-_Create_a_Background_Application.html?nodeid=1002140&vernum=0)

if you want GUI part also in your application.

[How to - Set up an alternate entry point](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820&vernum=0)

and for gps update

[Get location information updates](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8106/Get_location_position_updates_468129_11.jsp)

Comment: open BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file and check the option "Auto-run on startup"

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the BES server if you use a PHP or ASP.NET WebService.  You can consume that WebService on the Blackberry device using a JSON library found here:
http://www.json.org/

PHP and ASP.NET can receive JSON objects and parse them into objects on that specific programming language.